Getting html from Vue 3 component for use in map marker
I'm migrating from Nuxt 2 to Nuxt 3 and trying to work out how to do the equivalent of this in Vue 3:
import MapIcon from '~/components/elements/geo/map/marker/MapIcon.vue'

const IconInstance = Vue.extend(MapIcon)

const iconComponent = new IconInstance({
  propsData: {
    icon,
    wrapperClass
    color
  }
}).$mount().$el

markerElement.innerHTML = iconComponent.outerHTML

What I have tried so far:
const iconElement = document.createElement('div')

const iconComponent = render(
  h(
    MapIcon,
    {
      icon,
      wrapperClass,
      color
    },
    iconElement
  )
 )


Solved with:
const iconElement = document.createElement('div')

createApp(MapIcon, {
  icon,
  wrapperClass,
  color
}).mount(iconElement)

markerElement.innerHTML = iconElement.innerHTML

